# Angular How to loop over array of Component class files and render their template

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor

Im kinda lost here. Maybe I approach this from the wrong direction. I want to display a foldertree structure in my angular App from Files that have been placed on a drag and drop field.

I have created a component (FolderComponent) to hold all the data of the structure and the files on each folder level.

After some formating and sorting i now have an array of FolderComponent class files but im not sure if it is possible to render the html files of the component in the view. Since all i have is an array of component class files i cant just ngFor the associated template because then the new components have bo data attached to them.

Do i have to create new components and @Input() everything into them or is it possible via a directive or some other magic to tell angular to render the templates associated with the class file.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Indeed, you must not create a component by your own on the typescript file. You have to do all this in the HTML using an *ngFor on your data array. Then, in the HTML, depending on your data, you will generate a component or an other with *ngIf.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :)